# Build a list of grouped values

Tags: group-by, nvarchar, sybase-asa

I'm new to this page and this is the first time i post a question. Sorry for anything wrong. The question may be old, but i just can't find any answer for SQL AnyWhere.
I have a table like

```
Order |  Mark  
======|========   
1     | AA  
2     | BB  
1     | CC  
2     | DD  
1     | EE
```

I want to have result as following

```
Order | Mark  
1     | AA,CC,EE  
2     | BB,DD
```

My current SQL is

```
Select Order, Cast(Mark as NVARCHAR(20))  
From #Order  
Group by Order
```

and it just give me with result completely the same with the original table.

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ASA [`LIST()`](http://dcx.sap.com/1101/en/dbreference_en11/list.html) aggregate function (untested, you might need to enclose the `order` column name into quotes as it is also a reserved name):

```
SELECT Order, LIST( Mark )
FROM #Order
GROUP BY Order;
```

You can customize the separator character and order if you need.

Note: it is rather a bad idea to

- name your table and column name with like regular SQL clause (`Order by`)
- use the same name for column an table (`Order`)

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you so much. Also thanks for the column name advice & editting my post for better look.

Comment: You're welcome. If it addressed your issue, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)...